# Error: Error serializing props returned from getServerSideProps in "..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Trying to insert a condition inside `getServerSideProps`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const jwt = parseCookies(context).jwt || null;
  if (jwt) {
    const user = parseJwt(jwt);
    const userId = user.id;
    console.log(userId);
  } else {
    return {};
  }
  return {
    props: { jwt, userId },
  };
}
```

Getting the error:

> Error: Error serializing props returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/account".
> Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getServerSideProps: `{ props: { ... } }`.

How would you do it?

Comment: Whats does console.log(jwt) do? It seems like the jwt is an object with methods and other non-serializable keys.
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204363/3673659

Comment: `return { props: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ jwt, userId })) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) should return a really specific object, in the form of `{ props: {} }`, which the code you showed not respecting. Try changing it to:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const jwt = parseCookies(context).jwt || null;
  if (jwt) {
    const user = parseJwt(jwt);
    const userId = user.id;
    return {
      props: { jwt, userId },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
}
```